# What happens when you click the "Name" link on an Apache Index page

Tags: php, html, apache

When Apache is configured to allow it to build and display the `Index` of files in a folder, it displays several columns of data including: Name, Last Modified, Size, and Description.  For each column, it displays a clickable column header.  A typical Apache-built `Index` display looks like this:

[image]

When you click on, for example, the `Name` column header, Apache re-sorts the displayed index of items either in Ascending or Descending sequence.

I'm trying to write `index.php` to replace Apache’s default index-builder, and want to retain the sort-by-column functionality that Apache provides by default.  My current version of `index.php` creates a page which duplicates the `HTML` code that Apache generates to display the four column headers:

```
<table id='indexlist'>
    <tr class='indexhead'>
        <th class='indexcolicon'><img src='/icons/blank.gif' alt='[ICO]'></th>
        <th class='indexcolname'><a href='?C=N;O=D'>Name</a></th>
        <th class='indexcollastmod'><a href='?C=M;O=A'>Last modified</a></th>
        <th class='indexcolsize'><a href='?C=S;O=A'>Size</a></th>
        <th class='indexcoldesc'><a href='?C=D;O=A'>Description</a></th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The column headers display as clickable links as desired.  When I click any of them, my `index.php` script is invoked again, and it rebuilds the page.  But I can't figure out how to know which column header was clicked, or which sequence to sort.

How can my `index.php` determine which column header was clicked and how it should change the sort order?

Comment: If you use `&` instead of `;` in your links, you can use the `$_GET` superglobal to get the C and O values.

Comment: Look at bootstrap (https://getbootstrap.com/), it provides a LOT of cool html formatting, widgets, scripts, ...  And it provides css/javascript to setup a table with what you require.  You can research the web for javascript that does that as well, outside of bootstrap

Comment: Thanks @Nic3500 for the suggestion and link to [getbootstrap.com](https://getbootstrap.com/).  I've bookmarked it for future research.  But my focus now is learning a bit more PhP.  Thanks too for reformatting my code for better readability.

Comment: Bigger thanks to @rickenhaan for pointing me to `$_GET` which was what I had been looking for.  I knew that the `href` data was being passed back to me somehow when I clicked one of the table headers, but couldn't figure out how to get it.  I tried `argv` and `argc` but they were vacant.  Once I pursued your suggestion to use `$_GET` I discovered what I should have suspected all along -- that clicking a column header passed the associated data as parameters in the browser URL.  Thanks for your help.  I can't find any other way to acknowledge it, but I consider the question answered.